# Help understanding a construction of the lift of an analytic map between complex tori

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I'm trying understand the construction of the lift of an analytic map
$$f:\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$$ (with $\Lambda_i$ lattices in the complex plane) to a map $$F:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$$ with $\pi_2\circ F=f\circ \pi_1$ with $\pi_i$ the projections $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_i$.

The construction given does this by choosing $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t $\pi_2(\mu)=f(\pi_1(0))$ and then for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ choosing path in $\mathbb{C}$ from $0$ to $z$. From here we uniquely lift the path $f\pi_1\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ to $\mathbb{C}$ s.t $\tilde\gamma(0)=\mu$ and then define $F(z)=\tilde\gamma(1)$.

I'm struggling to see why $F(z)$ doesn't depend on the choice of $\gamma$, I thought about trying to apply the Monodromy theorem but I don't see how to do that. Any help would be great!

Comment: See also "path lifting property" regarding universal covering spaces...

Comment: My suggestion is to do some reading in basic algebraic topology (covering spaces, to be more precise). The result is a lifting property that will be covered pretty much in any textbook (Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" is freely available online). You can also deduce it from the "monodromy theorem" in complex analysis, since $F(z)$ is defined as a multivalued holomorphic function in a simply-connected domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use compactness.

Look at an arbitrary $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Now do the following. Translate $\Lambda_1$ so that $z$ is in the interior of one of the $\Lambda_1$ parallelograms, then translate $\Lambda_2$ so that the points on $\mathbb{C}$ corresponding to $f(z+\Lambda_1)$ are also the interior of the $\Lambda_2$ parallelograms.

There will then be an open neighbourhood  $B$ of $z$ such that $B$ is likewise in the interior of the $\Lambda_1$ parallelograms and $f(B+\Lambda_1)$ is in the interior of the $\Lambda_2$ parallelograms.

How many such open sets $B$ do we need to cover a closed $\Lambda_1$ parallelogram in $\mathbb{C}$? Of course finitely many will do, because the parallelogram is compact.

We now have a finite cover $B_1,\ldots,B_n$. On each $B_i$, if we fix the value of $F(z_i)$ for some $z_i\in B_i$, then there is a unique way of extending $F$ to the whole of $B_i$ so as to agree with $f$. That is because for this $z_i$, we fix the domain $B_i$ and range $F(B_i)$ as being contained in their respective parallelograms.

Now, fix some $z_1$, and use the overlaps between the $B_i$ to fix $F$ on the whole $\Lambda_1$ parallelogram in $\mathbb{C}$. We can do this because the parallelogram is connected. We now have enough information to fix $F$ on neighbouring $\Lambda_1$ parallelograms, and eventually on all $\Lambda_1$ parallelograms, meaning on the whole domain $\mathbb{C}$.